# Enabling Assets Image Edit Option for Assets in Amazon S3

Tags: assets, craft3, s3

What do I need to do in order to enable `Image Edit` option for Assets stored in Amazon S3?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with Imagik configuration. GD worked fine.

I fully remove Imagik, and reinstalled with it with default settings.

```
brew remove php71-imagik && brew services restart php71
```